# IPython not able to import variables from a module

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipython

I have a variable in a python file named `secrets.py` that I am trying to access from within IPython (specifically, an API key).  If I try `from secrets import API_KEY`, I get an error that it cannot import the variable.  What's interesting, however, is that a standard python environment (i.e. running `python` in a terminal) can import the variable just fine.  Both the standard python environment and the IPython are run from the same directory/virtual environment.  I'm not sure what's going wrong here.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I've had this happen where the Python used by IPython is different than the one used when just running `python`.  Could you double check the Python version in the welcome text when you run each `ipython` and `python` and confirm whether they're the same?

Comment: Can you share the specific error? If your Ipython is not in the correct working directory for whatever reason, it might be trying to find this variable in the built-in [secrets](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html) module. The import is working for me through both methods

Comment: @user1717828 I just confirmed that they are using the same python (3.6.14 in a virtual environment)

Comment: @shriakhilc The error is just a generic "ImportError: cannot import name 'API_KEY'"

Comment: This is a tough question to answer on SO, because it's more like debugging.  I can't give you a silver bullet, but try things like running `!pwd` from within IPython to confirm you're in the directory you think you are, and so forth.

Comment: @Catyre the end of that generic error is the important part, it will show you the path of `secrets.py` that it is trying to access. If I do it from the wrong location, I get `ImportError: cannot import name 'API_KEY' from 'secrets' (C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\secrets.py)`. Whereas if it is an issue with the variable, the path would be to the `secrets.py` in your working directory, not Python libs.

Comment: @shriakhilc What I shared with you was verbatim the error, nothing omitted, no given path.  With that being said, I fixed the problem.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IPython assumed that the `secrets.py` that I was importing was Python's native `secrets.py` and not the one I had made.  Rather than mess with path variables or whatever else would be needed to work around this, simply renaming my `secrets.py` to something else fixed the problem.  I'm still not sure why this behavior is different in a normal python environment, so if anyone can explain that, I'm all ears.

EDIT: With some guidance, I figured out why they were behaving differently.  Even though IPython's `sys.path` has the current working directory in it, it was after the folder where python's `secrets.py` existed.  So IPython checked that folder, saw that there was a `secrets.py`, and assumed that that was the one it was meant to import the API key from.  Whereas with the normal python, the CWD was the first entry in the list, so it found the correct API key no problem.

Answer (score 1):

`secrets` is [a Python module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html) for "generating cryptographically strong random numbers suitable for managing data such as passwords, account authentication, security tokens, and related secrets." The problem being of `ImportError`, it means that there is probably a conflict, because Python does not recognize `secrets.py` as your creation, but as the standard library module

The solution is to simply rename your file, changing its name.